# Amp-html - Can I use amp-position-observer to call AMP.setState() used in amp-bind?

Tags: amp-html

Is possible to set the AMP state using amp-position-observer?

I have tried the following code without success:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡>
<head>
  <script async="" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>
  <script custom-element="amp-position-observer" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-position-observer-0.1.js" async></script>
</head>

<body>
  <p [text]="'Hello ' + foo">Hello World</p>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <amp-position-observer
    intersection-ratios="0"
    on="enter:AMP.setState({foo: 'amp-bind'})"
    layout="nodisplay">
  </amp-position-observer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The solution adopted is explained in the relative GitHub thread: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/11735

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible by design. `setState` is a powerful (high-trust) action and only triggerable by direct user interaction. Scrolling is not considered a strong user interaction signal. Currently position-observer can only trigger low-trust actions such as playing or seeking amp-animation or videos.